# how to format / re indent a file (regarding its language) with Notepad v7.2.2?

Tags: format, notepad++

I want to format the text in any file that I am writing/modifying in Notepad ++ regarding the language that is written in(html, xml,...). For exemple (going back to line, proper organisation of the code...).I have the version v7.2.2 of notepad ++. I couldn't figure out how. I need some help please.

PS: I have no plugin manager.
[this is the toolbar in my Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1oSt.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Notepad choose the language based on file extention. [How to get notpadd recognize anexotic extention](http://todd.ropog.com/get-notepad-to-recognize-any-file-extension/)

Comment: hello @PierreLebon, thanks for the answer but I am not asking wether Notepad choose the language or not. I want to format the file( go to the line ... proper order in writing ) like in java formatter that we add ofr example in eclipse. And I don't know if this format is related to the language or just standard. I hope I was clear :)

Comment: I thought you where asking for  syntax highlighting based on Language. When you speek about format you mean re indenting an badly intended code for exemple? Or by reformat you want Something like [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/). but with no plugin?

Comment: @PierreLebon Yes, that's what I mean! when the code is messy then it is reorganized wether by re indenting or like what this tool do (the link you shared). And yes I am asking if there is a keyboard shortcut for that. because as I said I don't have a plugin manager and I don't know why. PS: thanks for the link :)

Comment: From notepad ++ web site : "Note that the most of plugins (including Plugin Manager) are not yet available in x64 " So you have have plugin manager. but the real issue in your question is the lack of accuraty. You wont find anything that can format any language. You can use a real EDI (vs community / eclipse). I am not aware of any multi-language pretifier.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/58884/auto-format-document-with-notepad

Comment: thanks for the response @PierreLebon.